# How would I extract metadata from an external website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to extract metadata from a website. More specifically, the description tag.
This is my code so far:

```
    <p><input id="submittedURL" type="text" placeholder="gimme that URL"></p>
    <p><button onclick="grabDesc()">Submit</button></p>
    <script>
        function grabDesc(){
            let desiredURL = document.getElementById("submittedURL").value;
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks.

Update: Went and ran my current code. No errors yet no results.
-> I would like to know how to extract the content of the description tag from `desiredURL`.

Comment: And what happens next? What have you tried? And what error messages and issues did you come across?

Comment: Originally, I was going to use php, as there's a built in function for extracting metadata. But since I am using GitHub Pages, I'm unable to utilize php.

Comment: I'm pretty sure PHP's [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) would be a great starting point and possibly easier than with JavaScript.

Comment: Wouldn't get_meta_tags() work as well?

Comment: Why yes, it would. I just have no idea what you are going to do with the data and if you needed something else on the web page beyond the description. Either way, this question does not really have an error, just an idea at the moment. Please update the question with an issue you need help with.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the input. The question has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If JavaScript then only with nodeJs. This is not possible from the browser only. You need a server. Otherwise with PHP, phyton, etc.

https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/web-scraping-javascript/